# Why not define rvalue reference to be rvalue expression?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, rvalue-reference

Let's consider the following code:

```
class X {
    std::vector<int> _v;
public:
    X(std::vector<int>&& v): _v(std::move(v)) {}
};
```

The compiler calls this constructor only for objects that can be moved. So why not just define an rvalue references to be rvalue expressions and don't write every time std::move for them?

The ctor member initialization list would look like:

```
_v(v)
```

But this would still be a move, not a copy.

Comment: Then we won't be able to move lvalues.

Comment: and if you'd like to copy it for some reason, would you need something like std::copy?

Comment: See http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3055.pdf

Comment: Could you please give an example?

Comment: @MFnx yes, std::copy would be used to call copy ctor

Comment: std::move returns its argument cast to a rvalue reference. It is useless (though harmless) to call it on things that are already rvalue references.

Comment: @n.m. As I have said we wouldn't call std::move then

Comment: Why are you calling std::move in your example? What you wrote is already equivalent to _v(v) without any "should' or "would".

Comment: @n.m. No, without std::move that code makes a copy

Comment: Arrrh sorry you are right, this was a momentary mental glitch.

Comment: Because the rvalue reference parameter has a name it is not itself considered an rvalue. `std::move()` basically just returns an unnamed rvalue reference, which is therefore an rvalue.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

While it is somewhat unfortunate to require the `std::move` in this common case, it was believed that an implicit move causing a run-time error in a few cases would be more harmful.

For example:

```
class Y
{
public:
    Y(const std::vector<int>& v);
};

class X {
    std::vector<int> v_;
    Y                y_;
public:
    X(std::vector<int>&& v): v_(v), y_(v) {}
};
```

In this modified example the constructor of `X` uses `v` twice.  If the first use of `v` implicitly moved, then the second use of `v` would quite likely not be getting the expected value.

Thus to avoid the accidental "use after move", if it has a name, then it can be used more than once, and is thus safer to treat it as an lvalue.

Comment: Instead of making an rvalue reference lvalue, why not introduce an `std::do_not_move` for such rare cases?

Comment: @xskxzr what type would `std::do_not_move` return?